# How to determine exact pixel measurements for mobile devices?

Tags: html, css, responsive-design

The developer tool of the browser is showing iPhone X is 375*812 which is not the actual resolution. I know CSS pixel is not always equal to display resolution. But my question is - **if I follow the simulated iPhone display in developer tools and set the width and height of the HTML elements to fit in the simulated display shown on the developer tools, will I get the same view in the actual iPhone?**

Answer (score 0):

Yes, but if you want to make your work much easier and not to hard coded the resolution values for each different devices, use css [mediaquery](https://www.w3schools.com/css/css_rwd_mediaqueries.asp)

Example:

```
/* Extra small devices (phones, 600px and down) */
@media only screen and (max-width: 600px) {...}

/* Small devices (portrait tablets and large phones, 600px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 600px) {...}

/* Medium devices (landscape tablets, 768px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 768px) {...}

/* Large devices (laptops/desktops, 992px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 992px) {...}

/* Extra large devices (large laptops and desktops, 1200px and up) */
@media only screen and (min-width: 1200px) {...}
```